# How to Store Window Parameters into a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, dimensions, sqldatatypes

I'm currently developing a program that scans the desktop for opened windows and stores the relevant window information into a database for retrieval later on.

I need to store things like the Window's Size and position on the desktop in pixels, into a relevant "Size" and "Position" field in the database.

The size could consist of either the Top-Left and Bottom-Right X&Y coordinates, or instead could contain the width and height of the window. Whichever is simpler.

The Position could contain just the X, Y, and Z coordinates of the Top-Left corner of the window, which would allow us to position the window correctly on the desktop.

What would be the best data type to accomplish this? I've seen mentions of people using the POLYGON data type, but it's one I've never seen before, and the examples I've seen are all for storing Latitude and Longitudes along with using "GetFromText" which is a function I'm having a hard time understanding as well.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Strange solution, but however... what operating system do you use?

Comment: Using Windows 7. Also, when you say Strange Solution, what do you mean? Would there be a better way to do this in general?

Comment: why not just store each discrete element in it's own column: x, y, width, height, z-index?

Comment: We'll do that instead. It would have been nice to been able to select a size, or a position, but if this makes implementation easier on the database size, then we'll go for the individual columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective it's more reliable (and more traditionaly) to store such parameters in Registry or ini-files. At the moment when app is launching, DB server can be not available. Besides, connecting to DB, performing select and so on just for restoring window coordinates and sizes looks very expensive. Launch process can take a long time.
And yes. Windows has integer screen coordinates, so it makes sense to use Integer data type for storing values separately x, y, w, h

Comment: Well, the application will function as a Client/Server application, and the MySQL db will reside on the Server. Now, if the client is unable to access the server (and in turn the db), then it would have no function at all, let alone playing with Windows.

All this to say, I thought it would sort of clutter our implementation to have both a db for some things, and .ini files for others. I figure if we have a db, we may as well use it. Am I wrong?